# Jquery with a weird bug

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the return key to function as the tab key but it dosent work with tables. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyq7/2/).

I'm not sure whats causing it not to work when I remove the table and use `<br />` it works perfectly. It also works with the jQuery calculator function. thought that was causing the problem but its not. I'm not sure if I'm asking jQuery to do something that a library would be better for.

### HTML

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="larger">field 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="sum1" name="sum1" class="sum" size="15" border="0"
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="sum2" name="sum2" class="ttw" size="15" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="cash" type="text" class="cash" id="cash1" value="" size="15"
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### jQuery

```
$('table:input').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("last")) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
        } else {
            $("form").submit();
        }
    }
});
$(function () {
    $('input[name^=sum]').keyup(function () {
        var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val(), 2) || 0; // Or parseInt if integers only
        var sum2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum2]').val(), 2) || 0;
        $('#cash1').val(sum1 + sum2);
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('input#cash1').blur(function () {
        var amt = parseFloat(this.value, 2) || 0;
        $(this).val('' + amt.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: looks like it's your selection on the focus portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/Beyq7/6/

`$(this).parent().next().children('input:first').focus();`

Comment: it should be noted that the selector binding to the keydown event is wrong, $('table :input') -> needs the space

Comment: This doesn't really cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector for finding the next input is wrong... try the following http://jsfiddle.net/Beyq7/4/

```
 $(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();
```

Also, when binding the key down event, you're not targeting the input correctly, use:

```
$('table input')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.  You need to update your markup so the last input has the class `last` and change your selector for the keydown to `td input`.  Then your selector getting the next input can look like this `$(this).parent().next().find('input').focus();`.

That should work.

JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bFRnf/

Comment: If this helped you can select it as the answer.